# positional sum of 2 numbers

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

How to sum 2 numbers digit by digit with pseudo code?

Note: You don't know the length of the numbers - if it has tens, hundreds, thousands...
      Units should be add to units, tens to tens, hundreds to hundreds.....
      If there is a value >= 10 in adding the units you need to put the value of that ten with "the tens"....

I tried

Start

Do

Add digit(x) in A to Sum(x)

Add digit(x) in B to Sum(x)

If Sum(x) > 9, then (?????)

digit(x) = digit(x+1)

while digit(x) in A and digit(x) in B is > 0

- How to show the result?

I am lost with that.....

Please help!

Comment: Can you please rephrase. It is unclear what you try to achieve.

Like, a number cannot be infinite, it will have bounds. 

If you are familiar with Linked list, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294048/add-two-big-numbers-represented-as-linked-lists-without-reversing-the-linked-lis should do

Comment: It's like...You have two numbers A and B with same or different amount of digits ( I mean -  one is bigger than other). You need to sum both but adding units to units, tens to tens, hundreds to hundreds, etc. If the sum of the units is bigger than 9 u should put it in the sum of tens... and it goes on until u find out that there is no more digits in A and B to be add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
 

n = minDigit(a, b) where a and b are the numbers.
let sum be a number.

m = maxDigit(a,b)
allocate maxDigit(a,b) + 1 memory for sum

carry = 0;

for (i = 1 to n)     
    temp = a[i] + b[i] + carry
    // reset carry
    carry = 0
    if (temp > 10) 
        carry = 1
        temp = temp - 10;

    sum[i] = temp

// one last step to get the leftover carry

if (digits(a) == digits(b) 
    sum[n + 1] = carry
    return

if (digits(a) > digits(b)
    toCopy = a
else
    toCopy = b

for (i = n to m)
    temp = toCopy[i] + carry
    // reset carry
    carry = 0
    if (temp > 10) 
        carry = 1
        temp = temp - 10;

    sum[i] = temp
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: Thank you, your code helped me a lot! But I cannot write with "programming language" code like (C, Java...).I should use the best "Easy Natural Language" possible. See this:     N receives the quantity of digits in A 
M receives de quantity of digits in B
If M is bigger than N, then N receives the value of M
Sum[N] =0
While N is bigger than 0, do
       The value of Sum[N] is Sum[N] plus A[N] plus B[N]
If the value of Sum[N] is bigger than 9
       Sum[N+1] receives 1

How increase the loop of N after these steps and show the final Sum? Something like : 
While N is bigger than 0, do
Sum[N]?

Comment: It don't show the indentation....N receives the quantity of digits in A 

M receives de quantity of digits in B

If M is bigger than N, then N receives the value of M

Sum[N] =0

While N is bigger than 0, do

       The value of Sum[N] is Sum[N] plus A[N] plus B[N]

If the value of Sum[N] is bigger than 9

       Sum[N+1] receives 1
How do I show the result of the Sum? Something like : 

While N is bigger than 0, do
Sum[N]???

Comment: Lets not distinguish. Let m be max digit (let it be for A). and m is the min digit (let it be for B). so till n, sum a[i] and b[i] and the carry.

Once >n, till m, just copy the a[i] (we assumed a[i] has max digit) till m. Did it answer your question ? It is the second part of the loop

Comment: I've added little more clarity, let me know if it helps. I could squeeze the two loops into one, but it won't be explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

`A` and `B` are the integers you want to sum.

Note that the while loop ends when all the three integers are equal to zero.

```
carry = 0
sum = 0
d = 1
while (A > 0 or B > 0 or carry > 0)
    tmp = carry + A mod 10 + B mod 10
    sum = sum + (tmp mod 10) * d
    carry = tmp / 10
    d = d * 10
    A = A / 10
    B = B / 10
```

Comment: Thank you for that! But I think I was not very clear....sorry. I cannot use "/", " * ", "mod"... the only sum I can do is when adding a digit with it's similar (units to units, etc) or using a counter.