# Sum of N numbers represented by linked lists

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, linked-list, sum

We can sum 2 numbers represented by linked lists(as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294048/add-two-big-numbers-represented-as-linked-lists-without-reversing-the-linked-lis)) using-
1. stack
2. Recursion 
Now I want to generalize this method for 'N' linked lists. What would be the **best** approach to deal with this problem?

Comment: in the representation, the first digit is on the top or on the bottom of the stack?

Comment: Define **best**. Memory footprint? Execution time? Ease of coding or maintenance? Weighted combination of these three? Something entirely different - what?

Comment: @svs list is like 4->5->1->2 for number 4512.

Comment: @laune i am looking for memory optimized approach.

Comment: So N stacks in parallel is out. Add two at a time - see answer by @aniketsiva. What else did you expect?

Comment: @laune so generalization for N lists would simplified to adding 2 lists n-1 times, what else can we think apart from this obvious approach. Like updating recursive approach for N lists. But this approach will increase a lot of checks. And also as aniket also pointed out that recursive approach is no different from "stack" approach so how should we compare between these approaches?

Comment: Recursive means that the stack is in the stack segment, otherwise it's an object. Running several recursions in parallel just requires as many stacks. Apart from some overhead for an object (either N stacks or an array[N] per recursion level), there's not much difference.

Comment: Recursion would require less memory if the lists were *doubly linked* lists.

Answer (score 2):

1. using N stacks would be good solution.
2. You can also add 2 lists at a time and do this N-1 times to add all lists.
3. Generalize recursive method to work for N lists.
   These are the approaches but still not able tell you what could be best among them.

Comment: @laune since recursive approach is similar to using stack approach as in both the cases stack is maintained, thats why hard to compare both.